# Mysql server not starting on uwamp 3.1

Tags: uwamp

Mysql Server stop working after 5 seconds (fresh install of uwamp)

Uwamp version 3.1 started with Administrator rights on windows 10 32bits.

Here is the Mysql log :

```
2016-02-25T13:53:19.049733Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-02-25T13:53:19.049733Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2016-02-25T13:53:19.049733Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.
2016-02-25T13:53:19.049733Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2016-02-25T13:53:19.050735Z 0 [Note] C:\UwAmp\bin\database\mysql-5.7.11\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.11) starting as process 6552 ...
2016-02-25T13:53:19.117843Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open shared library 'C:\UwAmp\bin\database\mysql-5.7.11\lib\plugin\keyring_file.dll' (errno: 126 Le module spécifié est introuvable.)
2016-02-25T13:53:19.122851Z 0 [ERROR] Couldn't load plugin named 'keyring_file' with soname 'keyring_file.dll'.
2016-02-25T13:53:19.127856Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-02-25T13:53:19.130861Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2016-02-25T13:53:19.132864Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-02-25T13:53:19.134867Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-02-25T13:53:19.137871Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2016-02-25T13:53:19.139875Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-02-25T13:53:21.056091Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2016-02-25T13:53:21.087354Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-02-25T13:53:21.234144Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile101 size to 48 MB
2016-02-25T13:53:22.659215Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 48 MB
2016-02-25T13:53:24.176685Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file .\ib_logfile101 to .\ib_logfile0
2016-02-25T13:53:24.176685Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=2602779
2016-02-25T13:53:24.176685Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-02-25T13:53:24.192315Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 87 in a file operation.
2016-02-25T13:53:24.192315Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2016-02-25T13:53:24.192315Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: File .\ib_logfile0: 'aio read' returned OS error 187. Cannot continue operation
2016-02-25T13:53:24.192315Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Answer (score 3):

In the uwAmp control panel, click on XDebug client and select "Remove MySql log".Then try to start MySQL in the top of control panel. It must works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try the following://in my case it worked

Step 1: Download and install the wamp server app from the http://www.wampserver.com/

Step 2: Open the wamp server installation folder of the wamp server app. In my case is C:\wamp64

Step 3: Once inside the wamp folder, open the folders in the following sequence bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14

Step 4: You should find in here a folder called lib

Step 5: Copy the folder lib to your UwAmp folder but not just to folder but to the UwAmp\bin\database\mysql-5.7.11- here.

Step 6: Restart the UwAmp or stop the server and restart it again.

Step 7: At this stage the MySQl should work.